# Find an element that generates the Ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, ideals, finite-fields

> Given the ideal: $A$:={$\sum_{i∈I}T^i|$  $I $ finite,$|I|$ even} ⊂ $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ find an element that generates it.

Now I know that it has to be $A=a$ $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, where $a$ is the element that I'm looking for and $a≠0$.

Has it any sense to let $a=1$? but then $A=\mathbb{F}_2[X]$. I'm not really sure what I should look at first

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Note that for any $p(T)=\sum_{i\in I}T^i\in A$, it holds $p(1)=|I|=0$. This gives
$$
(T-1)=(T+1)\ | \ p(T)
$$ for any $p\in A$.